# how msg.vlaue is used and given value in a function

Tags: solidity

```js
function BuyACoffee(string memory _message, string memory _name)public payable
    {
        require(msg.value > 0, "you don't have enough balance");
    }
```

how is `msg.value` assigned in this function?

Where is it getting stored?

Answer (score 1):

1. msg.value it is the amount of native token you send in your transaction. So it can't be assign in smart contract
2. It just a alltribute of msg come with transaction. For more variable like msg.sender you can come [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_variables.htm) to check out.

Answer (score 0):

msg.value is an attribute of a special variable that is called msg.
This variable get filled when someone execute an smart contract, it contain all the metadata of the message that caused the contract to be executed:

-the numeric representation of the ethereum that the sender sent.

-the name of the sender

-the data provided by message.

-the amount of gas provided by the message

-the price of the gas

-the function signature